# Googles Places API

Tags: iphone, asp.net, django

We are developing an application that utilizes several of the supported place types in the Google Places API. But, we have noticed that the supported type, restaurant code, is different from the restaurant info you would find at the bottom page of a Google page on a smart phone. Example; the restaurant info given from a smart phone provides restaurant details and location. The one listed in Google Places API does not show the same info. Please inform us how we can obtain the codes for the same info that’s provided on the Google page from a smart phone. Is it free or part of a premium deal with Google? Thanks, and I hope this is clear.
Arthur

Answer (score 0):

The Google Places database is different from Google Maps.

I'd imagine that at some point, Google would unite the two.

You could match by lat/long & name. This would probably work for at least half the time. The other half means the name & lat/long from both databased maybe a little different.

Comment: Thanks Danny, my developer and I considered your reply.